# mysqli delete query not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm writing a PHP script to delete a row from a MySQL database by id.
The value of the id is passed as a query string and stored in a variable.

The query runs normally, with no errors, but no rows are affected.

Here is my code, can somebody please point out what's wrong with it?

Thanks.

PHP Code:

```
$delete = $_GET['killthisguy'];
$sqlDel = "DELETE FROM `pba_files` WHERE id=".$delete;
$res = mysqli_query($cxn, $sqlDel);
$affRows = mysqli_affected_rows($cxn);
```

Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pba_files` (
`id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`chap_id` int(2) default NULL,
`cat_id` varchar(2) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
`is_video` tinyint(1) default NULL,
`file_location` varchar(220) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
`clean_filename` varchar(116) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
`description` varchar(1026) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=611 ;
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: Please immediately read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flow-control-statements.html) and begin [learning to use `prepare()execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with `?` value placeholders in MySQLi. This is imperative.

Comment: `http://example.com/yourscript.php?killthisguy='+OR+id+IS+NOT+NULL--` and all your rows are gone.

Comment: @1nflktd I get no error, it just doesn't delete anything.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank you. I'm new to PHP, and this is just practising on my own.

Comment: @MichalisAntoniou If you're new, that is all the better reason to begin learning the right way from the beginning, so you don't have to change bad habits later :)  The web is full of _terrible_ old tutorials that teach the wrong way.  http://www.phptherightway.com/

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski hehehe not all rows are gone , but all of his guys are gone :) . because hes using kill this guy :).

Comment: @Michael Berkowski the proper sql injection would be this, killthisguy="0'+OR+id+IS+NOT+NULL --", you'd have to end his starting single quote, and end the query in a comment to ignore the original ending single quote.. or simular ( might not need the +'s, but i would have to try it, what was that url again ... lol J/P )  "DELETE FROM `pba_files` WHERE id='0' OR id IS NOT NULL --'" .. that would wipe the table out.

Comment: one note often overlooked with parametrized queries, is you will still want to sanitize any order by or limit values or dynamic table / column names ( anything injected ), because these are not protected by mysqli or PDO and would allow someone to complete the end of the query and add a whole other query on such as "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT $v" ~ "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 LIMIT 0; DELETE FROM table WHERE 1;"  or worse INSERT INTO admin_users ......

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the ' from the "id" because it is not a string, it is an int (from the database point of view)

```
$delete = $_GET['killthisguy'];
$sqlDel = "DELETE FROM `pba_files` WHERE id=".$delete;
$res = mysqli_query($cxn, $sqlDel);
$affRows = mysqli_affected_rows($cxn);
```

Also are you sure that the "id" exists in the table?

Comment: That doesn't work either. Any other ideas? The id does exist in the table also.

Comment: Could you please write here the output of 
var_dump($affRows);

Comment: The output is int(-1)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pba_files` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `chap_id` int(2) default NULL,
  `cat_id` varchar(2) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `is_video` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `file_location` varchar(220) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `clean_filename` varchar(116) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `description` varchar(1026) character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=611 ;

Comment: I added it on the description as well.

Comment: did you try printing the actual text of the query out, then you could try ruining it in phpmyadmin, you might have a try catch somewhere suppressing the errors etc..? such as echo $sqlDel;

Comment: you have int(3) for your id column what is the id is it over 128 int(3) doesn't mean < 999, personaly i always do int(10) unsigned not null auto increment. for primary keys

Comment: I did echo $sqlDel, then pasted the result in phpmyadmin and the row was deleted.

Comment: then you may have an issue with your database connection, can you run a select query in code?

Comment: ok int(3) is covered here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html, i had an issue with that at work, but seems i was mistaken on the size so confusing, they way it is

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. My access rights were just messed up, delete was not allowed for my user.

Comment: Awesome, glad we helped you get it sorted out, that is always what I do when a query wont run, just go right to the source in phpmyadmin and run the query you are generating.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was just a careless mistake I made when setting up my access rights. DELETE was not allowed for my user on the database.

Thanks for all your help guys.